# How to set header request in reactjs

Tags: python, security, reactjs

I'm trying to set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to be able to skip the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.test.dev:8090/glasses/import/log/qa/qa2/20170106?headers%5BAc…llow-Headers%5D=Origin%2C%20X-Requested-With%2C%20Content-Type%2C%20Accept. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.test.dev:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

But I'm not getting the desired result. The client side is implemented in reactjs and send a get request to a python web app. Here is my code:

```
class InfoBox extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {items:[]};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    Request.get('http://www.test.dev:8090/glasses/import/log/qa/qa2/20170106', {
      headers:{
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
      }
    }) 
      .then((response) => {
      this.setState({items:response});
    });
  }
  render() {
      const content = this.state.items.map(function(item) {return <div>{item}</div>});
      return (
        <div >{content}</div>
      );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CORS is not enabled from the `client` side, rather the server side.

In a normal `http` request, the browser will initially send an options request, to verify that the source has the permission to access the resources. The server will respond back with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. If the source is mentined in the headers, browser will then send the Appropriate `PUT, POST, GET, DELETE` request.

You need to specify these header in you `python server` reponse

Comment: Thanks, it works after that I moved the CORS to python. Now, I feel how silly was my question :D. I tried applying this change in request and response on client side but never tried it in server side.

Comment: No Problem, it happens will almost all of us :)